# PC won't boot with more than 1 stick of RAM

Tags: memory, cpu, troubleshooting, quad-core

I've got the following computer. I just put in a new CPU QX9650 and I ran into this problem since making this hardware change.

Whenever I put more than 1 of my 4 sticks of RAM into my machine it won't load an OS. It'lwl go through the BIOS,but BSOD on Windows load. It also won't let me install an OS from the disk or boot into Linux.

I ran memtest with all RAM 4 sticks in, and I got 10k+ errors on test5. Each stick of ram on it's own is fine and functions properly. I only have problems when all 4 RAM sticks are in the machine at the same time.

Specs:

- CPU: QX9650
- mobo: Asus P5B 2104 BIOS
- RAM: 2xPC25400 DDR2 , 2 x PC2 6400 both OCZ

Is the problem on my end or is the CPU faulty?

Comment: The RAM + Mobo combo worked fine before the CPU upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that some of the RAM sticks are working at a frequency which is too high for them, or the CPU tries to use Dual Channel with memory which doesn't support it.

Here are some things to try:

1. Plug in the RAM sticks in different configurations. Try putting matched sticks in each bank. There should be 4 RAM slots, laid out on the motherboard so that there are 2 pairs that are very close to each other, and there's a larger distance between the pairs. Slots within each pair should have identical RAM sticks. In your case one pair would receive the 2xPC2-5400 memory and the second the 2xPC2-6400 memory).
2. Try turning off Dual Channel in BIOS.
3. Try downclocking the DRAM frequency in BIOS.

Comment: Tried all 3 :( no luck!